# Failed to compile component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render the `<Login />` component within the `<Home />` component and I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/home/Home.js
```

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './login/Login' in 
'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\dev\backend\react-express\client\src\components\home'
```

Here is `Home.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./login/Login";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <h1>TodoApp</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the Homepage!</p>
      <Login />
      <Link to="about" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        Learn more
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the folder structure where you have your `<Login>` component added in the project? Probably `"./login/Login"` is not the way to import. Thanks!

Comment: `...src\components\home\login\login.js` is the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to import `Login` component from the wrong path. I guess you should try importing it like this

`import Login from "../login/Login";`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're importing Login via wrong path. Please check all the paths and try.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was trying to access `src\components\login\Login.js` from `src\components\home\Home.js`. `.\login` is not present in `.\home`, so I have to add an extra `'.'` to `.\login` when importing `Login.js`.